# Gulp deprecate - how to mark some task as deprecated?

Tags: gulp

Is there any easy way to mark some **gulp** tasks as deprecated?

```
gulp.task('task-name', function () {
    console.warn("The `gulp task-name` task is deprecated, it will be removed in next release."); // poore implementation for depreciating some task
});
```

As I want to let users to know, that some task will be removed from package in the future. They should be prepared for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp itself uses [`deprecated`](https://github.com/contra/deprecated) to deprecate [parts of its API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/bfb8522/index.js#L56). That's probably the closest thing to an "official" way of deprecating as you will get:

```
var deprecated = require('deprecated');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('task-name', deprecated.method(
  gutil.colors.yellow('task-name is deprecated'), 
  gutil.log, 
  function() {
    // your task
  }));
```

Comment: Your investigation was better than mine : )